# PDDocument.load(file) isnt a method (PDFBox)

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, pdfbox

I wanted to make a simple program to get text content from a pdf file through Java. Here is the code:

```
    PDFTextStripper ts = new PDFTextStripper();
    File file = new File("C:\\Meeting IDs.pdf");
    PDDocument doc1 = PDDocument.load(file);
    String allText = ts.getText(doc1);
    String gradeText = allText.substring(allText.indexOf("GRADE 10B"), allText.indexOf("GRADE 10C"));
    System.out.println("Meeting ID for English: "
            + gradeText.substring(gradeText.indexOf("English") + 7, gradeText.indexOf("English") + 20));
```

This is just part of the code, but this is the part with the problem.
The error is: `The method load(File) is undefined for the type PDDocument`

---

I have learnt using PDFBox from JavaTPoint. I have followed the correct instructions for installing the PDFBox libraries and adding them to the Build Path.
My PDFBox version is 3.0.0
I have also searched the source files and their methods, and I am unable to find the load method there.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're a newbie, stay with 2.0.23. It's fine. The 3.0.0-RC is a release candidate, a bit like a beta. We already found several severe bugs.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As per the [3.0 migration guide](https://pdfbox.apache.org/3.0/migration.html) the `PDDocument.load` method has been replaced with the `Loader` method:

> For loading a PDF PDDocument.load has been replaced with the Loader
> methods. The same is true for loading a FDF document.
>
> When saving a PDF this will now be done in compressed mode per
> default. To override that use PDDocument.save with
> CompressParameters.NO_COMPRESSION.
>
> PDFBox now loads a PDF Document incrementally reducing the initial
> memory footprint. This will also reduce the memory needed to consume a
> PDF if only certain parts of the PDF are accessed. Note that, due to
> the nature of PDF, uses such as iterating over all pages, accessing
> annotations, signing a PDF etc. might still load all parts of the PDF
> overtime leading to a similar memory consumption as with PDFBox 2.0.
>
> The input file must not be used as output for saving operations. It
> will corrupt the file and throw an exception as parts of the file are
> read the first time when saving it.

So you can either swap to an earlier 2.x version of PDFBox, or you need to use the new `Loader` method. I believe this should work:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Meeting IDs.pdf");
PDDocument doc1 = Loader.loadPDF(file);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to PDFBox, so should I keep using 3.0.0, or sould I downgrade to version 2.x ? What would you recommend?

Comment: @9C35OjasPednekar I strongly recommend going back to the latest 2.x version at least until a supported 3.0 release comes out. One of the contributors left a comment abovt saying that there are a number of severe bugs in 3.0 RC